# Detect click outside and change state of component on Typescript (SolidJS)

Tags: typescript, solid-js

i learn SolidJS framework and have problem. I want to change state of element with directives, but it dont work. What do i do wrong? Full project - https://github.com/XPahanX/editor (not actual)

Component:

```
import { Component, createSignal, ParentComponent, Show } from 'solid-js';
import clickOutside from '../directives/click-outside';

clickOutside;

const EditorBlockMenu: Component<{fun: () => false}> = (prop) => {
    return (
        <div class='editor-block-menu' use:clickOutside={prop.fun}>
            <div><button>Delete</button></div>
            <div><button>Move Up</button></div>
            <div><button>Move Down</button></div>
        </div>
    )
}

const EditorBlockBtn: ParentComponent = () => {
    const [toggle, setToggle] = createSignal(false)
    const isToggle = () => setToggle(!toggle())

    return (
        <div classList={{'editor-block-btn': !toggle()}}>
            <button onClick={isToggle}>
                
            </button>
            <Show
                when={toggle()}
                fallback={<></>}
            >
                <EditorBlockMenu fun={() => setToggle(false)}/>
            </Show>
        </div>
    )
}

export default EditorBlockBtn;
```

Directive:

```
import { onCleanup } from "solid-js";

// https://www.solidjs.com/tutorial/bindings_directives?solved
// need fix
export default function clickOutside(el:Element, accessor: () => false) {
  const onClick = (e: Event) => 
    !el.contains(e.target as Node) && accessor();
  document.body.addEventListener("click", onClick);
  onCleanup(() => document.body.removeEventListener("click", onClick));
}

declare module "solid-js" {
  namespace JSX {
    interface Directives {
      clickOutside: () => false;
    }
  }
}
```

As far as I understand, the function `setToggle()` does not work in `fun={}`. I am not strong in Typescript, I hope for your help.

---

I use first answer, but get an error:

```
const EditorBlockMenu: Component = () => {
    return (
        <div class='editor-block-menu'>
            <div><button>Delete</button></div>
            <div><button>Move Up</button></div>
            <div><button>Move Down</button></div>
        </div>
    )
}

const EditorBlockBtn: ParentComponent = () => {
    const [toggle, setToggle] = createSignal(false)
    const isToggle = () => setToggle(!toggle())
    let ref: HTMLDivElement

    const handleClick = (event: MouseEvent) => {
        if(!ref.contains(event.target as Node)) { // withuot `as Node` highlights in red
          setToggle(false)
        }
      }
    
      onMount(() => {
        document.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
      })
      
      onCleanup(() => {
        document.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
      })

    return (
        <div classList={{'editor-block-btn': !toggle()}}>
            <button onClick={isToggle}>
           
            </button>
            <Show
                when={toggle()}
                fallback={<></>}
            >
                <EditorBlockMenu ref={ref!}/>
            </Show>
        </div>
    )
}

export default EditorBlockBtn;
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6jun.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tutorial on SolidJS's website that demonstrates the very same use case:

https://www.solidjs.com/tutorial/bindings_directives

Directive are good when you replicate a functionality for multiple elements, otherwise you can implement it yourself directly inside any component:

```js
import { createSignal, onCleanup, onMount } from 'solid-js';

export const App = () => {
  let ref: HTMLDivElement;
  const [show, setShow] = createSignal(true);

  const handleClick = (event: MouseEvent) => {
    if(!ref.contains(event.target)) {
      setShow(false);
    };
  };

  onMount(() => {
    document.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
  });
  
  onCleanup(() => {
    document.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
  });

  return (
  <div ref={ref!}>
    Visible: {show() ? 'true': 'false'}
  </div>
  );
};
```

https://playground.solidjs.com/anonymous/c933b32f-67cb-45e9-843c-6555144c33f5

Comment: I know, but I wanted to learn how to apply directives by this example. In any case, I changed the code taking into account your answer and I get an error (from DevTools): `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'contains')
    at HTMLDocument.handleClick`

Comment: I forgot to add that I added a new code to the question

Comment: @Pahan Use `ref.contains((event as any).target` instead of  as Node.

Comment: I wrote `if(!ref.contains((event as any).target))`, but the error remained the same(

Comment: I also tried to move the block from the component `<div class='editor-block-menu'>...` and add `ref={ref!}` => `<div class='editor-block-menu' ref={ref!}>`, but in this case the submenu was not displayed at all. Without `ref={ref!} submenu display normally.

Comment: I think it's about the location of the button outside the submenu itself, so the submenu is displayed and immediately deleted using `handleClick`. I added an image to the question

Answer (score -1):

In general, after a few trials and errors, I decided on a new method that works. Of course, I deviated from the originally set path, but I think there is no better solution for this task.

```
const EditorBlockBtn: ParentComponent = () => {
    const [toggle, setToggle] = createSignal(false)
    const isToggle = () => setToggle(!toggle())
    let divRef: HTMLDivElement
    let btnRef: HTMLButtonElement

    const handleClick = (event: MouseEvent) => {
        if(!divRef.contains(event.target as Node) && !btnRef.contains(event.target as Node)) {
            setToggle(false)
        }
    }
    
    onMount(() => {
        document.addEventListener('click', handleClick)
    })
    
    onCleanup(() => {
        document.removeEventListener('click', handleClick)
    })

    return (
        <div classList={{'editor-block-btn': !toggle()}}>
            <button onClick={isToggle} ref={btnRef!}>
           
            </button>
            <Show
                when={toggle()}
                fallback={<></>}
            >
                <div class='editor-block-menu' ref={divRef!}>
                    <div><button>Delete</button></div>
                    <div><button>Move Up</button></div>
                    <div><button>Move Down</button></div>
                </div>
            </Show>
        </div>
    )
}

export default EditorBlockBtn;
```